# Cannot copy .DLL files using cookbook_file in chef on windows

Tags: windows-10, chef

I am using `chef` to create setup files for a local build on windows 10 (e.g, using ChefDK with `chef-client -z -o win10-setup`).

I want to use `cookbook_file` or `remote_directory` to copy `*.dll` files which I have locally in my cookbook. I have found that if I have a .dll in my cookbook, chef will complain is does not see the file and throws `Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound`.

For example, if I have `[cookbook]\files\default\notepadplusplus\plugins\someplugin.dll`

and try:

```
cookbook_file "#{ENV["USERPROFILE"]}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Notepad++\\plugins\\someplugin.dll" do
  source 'notepadplusplus/plugins/someplugin.dll'
  action :create_if_missing
  only_if { ::File.exist?("#{ENV["PROGRAMFILES"]}/Notepad++/notepad++.exe") }
end
```

it will not work. However, if I rename `someplugin.dll` to `someplugin.dll.plugin` and then change my code to the following, where I update the `source` accordingly

```
cookbook_file "#{ENV["USERPROFILE"]}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Notepad++\\plugins\\someplugin.dll" do
  source 'notepadplusplus/plugins/someplugin.dll.plugin'
  action :create_if_missing
  only_if { ::File.exist?("#{ENV["PROGRAMFILES"]}/Notepad++/notepad++.exe") }
end
```

it will work.

However, this is not an ideal solution because I don't want to do `cookbook_file` for each file individually, but instead use `remote_directory` to copy all of the plugins in the folder at once.

I ran a test with `remote_directory` and found that it will copy over other files that are not `*.dll` but will skip the `*.dll` files

I do not want to have to use a lot of scripts to rename files once copied over as that seems like it could be error prone.

Is there any particular reason chef doesn't seem to think `.dll` files does not exist or is somehow configured to ignore these files? It seems to filter on the actual file extension and not on data in the file since the renaming trick above works.

Answer (score 2):

While this question was asked a year ago, I recently came across this issue myself and was able to produce a solution for my situation. Responding so others that stumble upon this post have a chance at relief.

---

Check that your `chefignore` file in the root of your cookbook does not contain an entry for .dll files. If you created your cookbook with the `chef generate cookbook [cookbook_name]` command (or perhaps the equivalent knife command), you can expect your `chefignore` file to have this entry.

An example of the section in the `chefignore` file you will want to modify:

```
## COMPILED ##
##############
a.out
*.o
*.pyc
*.so
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*/rdoc/
```

You can either comment the offending line or remove it completely.

---

In my particular situation, I only wanted to use the .dll in a nested cookbook that was being used for testing. My solution was to copy the `chefignore` file into the root of my nested cookbook, and modify the file there.

Example path for inner cookbook's `chefignore` file:

`[outer_cookbook]\test\cookbooks\[inner_cookbook]\chefignore`

Note that the inner cookbook was by itself in my runlist, I'm not sure what happens when you have conflicting `chefignore` files in the same runlist.

Good luck.